# How to create an object by accumulating two fields from a list of another object?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of objects Room:

```
class Room {
    int guestCount;
    List<String> sunglassBrands;
}
```

I want to get the total guests in all the rooms and all of their sunglass brands together like this:

```
class Guest {
    int guestCount;
    List<Sunglass> sunglasses;
}

class Sunglass {
    String brandName;
}
```

Now, this is might be a straightforward way to do it:

```
AtomicInteger numberOfGuests = new AtomicInteger();
List<Sunglass> sunglassBrandsList = new ArrayList<>();
rooms.forEach(
            room -> {
              numberOfGuests.getAndAdd(room.getGuestCount());
              sunglassBrandsList.addAll(
                  room.getSunglassBrands.stream()
                      .map(
                          brand -> {
                            Sunglass sunglass = new Sunglass();
                            sunglass.setBrandName(brand);
                            return sunglass;
                          })
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            });
Guest guest = new Guest();
guest.setGuestCount(numberOfGuests.get());
guest.setSunglassBrands(sunglassBrandsList);
```

Can this be done in a more elegant way in a single iteration? I think I can use `reduce` here but I am not quite sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the next way.

```
int numberOfGuests = rooms.stream().mapToInt(Room::getGuestCount).sum();
List<Sunglass> sunglassBrands = rooms.stream().map(Room::getSunglassBrands).flatMap(List::stream).map(Sunglass::ofBrandName).collect(Collectors.toList());
// creation of object
```

**Note:** `Sunglass::ofBrandName` is a static method with next implementation

```
public static Sunglass ofBrandName(String brandName) { 
  Sunglass sunglass = new Sunglass();
  sunglass.brandName = brandName;
  return sunglass;
}
```

You can create a private method in your class to create sunglass or just hardcode lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `reduce`, you can use the three-argument version of it.

```
Guest guest = rooms.stream()
       .reduce(new Guest(),
               (guest, room) -> {
                   guest.addGuests(room.getGuestCount());
                   guest.addSunglasses(room.getSunglassBrands()
                           .stream().map(Sunglass::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                   return guest;
               },
               (guest1, guest2) -> {
                   guest1.addGuests(guest2.getGuestCount());
                   guest1.addSunglasses(guest2.getSunglasses());
                   return guest1;
               });
```

For this, I have added the below two methods to the `Guest` class and initialized the instance variables.

```
class Guest {
    int guestCount = 0;
    List<Sunglass> sunglasses = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addGuests(int guestCount) {
       this.guestCount += guestCount;
    }

    public void addSunglasses(List<Sunglass> sunglasses) {
        this.sunglasses.addAll(sunglasses);
    }
}
```

and added a constructor to the `Sunglass` class. (If you don't want to do this, have to change the `.map(Sunglass::new)` to a lambda expression to create a `Sunglass` and set the brand name (like how you have done).

```
public Sunglass(String brandName) {
    this.brandName = brandName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stream to convert the list of sunglasses to Sunglass objects but other than that, I would use a regular loop for the rooms.

- simply allocate a guest instance.
- and using getters and setters, update the instance.
- depending on your requirements you might want to use a `Set<Sunglass>` instead of a `List<Sungclass>` to avoid duplicates.

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new Room(23, List.of("brandA, BrandB")),
                new Room(33, List.of("brandC", "brandD"))));

Guest guest = new Guest();

for (Room room : rooms) {
    // update the guest count here
    guest.setGuestCount(
            guest.getGuestCount() + room.getGuestCount());
    
    // create a new list of Sunglass instances here.
    // and add to the guest instance
    guest.getSunglasses().addAll(room.getBrands().stream()
            .map(Sunglass::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
System.out.printl(guest);
```

prints

```
[56, [brandA, BrandB, brandC, brandD]]
```

The supporting class definitions.

```
class Room {
    int guestCount;
    List<String> sunglassBrands;
    
    public Room(int count, List<String> list) {
        this.guestCount = count;
        this.sunglassBrands = list;
    }
    
    public int getGuestCount() {
        return guestCount;
    }
    
    public List<String> getBrands() {
        return sunglassBrands;
    }
    
}

class Guest {
    int guestCount = 0;
    List<Sunglass> sunglasses = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public int getGuestCount() {
        return guestCount;
    }
    
    public void setGuestCount(int count) {
        this.guestCount = count;
    }
    
    public List<Sunglass> getSunglasses() {
        return sunglasses;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%d, %s]", guestCount, sunglasses);
    }
}

class Sunglass {
    String brandName;
    
    public Sunglass(String name) {
        this.brandName = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return brandName;
    }
}
```